# Rounding a Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran the following query:

```
SELECT 
    year, month_name, 
    south / (south + west + midwest + northeast) * 100.0 AS perc_south, 
    west / (south + west + midwest + northeast) * 100.0 AS perc_west, 
    midwest / (south + west + midwest + northeast) * 100.0 AS perc_midwest, 
    northeast / (south + west + midwest + northeast) * 100.0 AS perc_northeast
FROM 
    tutorial.us_housing_units 
WHERE 
    year > 2000
ORDER BY 
    year DESC;
```

It returns percentages that span many decimal places.

How can I round the resulting columns to (let's say) 4 decimal places?

Comment: using data from www.modeanalytics.com  SQL tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way is to convert to decimal:

```
convert(decimal(6, 2), south/(south+west+midwest+northeast)*100.0)
```

This actually stores the value using two decimal places.  Downstream applications generally respect the format.

You can also use the `round()` function to round the value (although this does not change the type).  Or use the `str()` function to convert the value to a string.